# iOS App: Setting custom font on UIButton clears the button

Tags: ios, uibutton, truetype

I am having a weird issue with custom fonts on iOS.

I've included a TTF font in my project and am programatically setting it for a bunch of UI controls - I've tried many ways of doing this and they all produce the same odd result:

For UILabels it works fine (except multi-line labels collapse to one line, very annoying), but for UITextEdit and UIButton, the label is cleared (not white, or transparent; it's gone).

Here is the code I use for labels:

```
- (void)setLabelFontOn:(UILabel *)label
{
  label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Regular" size:label.font.pointSize];
}
```

And here is the code I use for UIButton

```
- (void)setButtonFontOn:(UIButton *)button
{
  [self setLabelFontOn:button.titleLabel];
}
```

It's doing the exact same thing! Yet one works, the other doesn't.

I've tried calling it on a view collection in viewDidAppear and in viewDidLoad. I've tried to create a custom UIButton and implement the above in awakeFromNib - all has the same result - there appear to be no way I can get that font to show on a UIButton.

Is there some funky requirement on fonts used on button UILabel's that are different from a regular UILabel?

Comment: How are you initializing the button?

Comment: In UIBuilder - the button is there. If I don't do anything with the titleLable, it looks just fine using whatever font I specified in UIBuilder. I just can't change the font without clearing the button text.

Comment: Tried another TTF and it works fine - something must be broken in the font I was trying to use. Still don't understand how it could work for UILabel then...